# Компилятор не видит в последовательности символов тип данных

Tags: c++

Почему вот это не компилируется:

```
class Monster
{
public:

    Monster(MonsterTypes type, std::string name, std::string roar, int hit_points)
    {

    }
    enum MonsterTypes
    {
        DRAGON,
        GOBLIN,
        OGRE,
        ORC,
        SKELETON,
        TROLL,
        VAMPIRE,
        ZOMBIE,
        MAX_MONSTER_TYPES
    };
private:
    MonsterTypes m_type;
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_roar;
    int m_hit_points;
};
```

Выдаёт такое: `expected ')' before 'type'`.

Я уже понел, что компилятор не видит, что я уже определил последовательность символов `MonsterTypes`, как тип данных, и это исправляется перенесением определения типа перед конструктором. Но почему не работает первый вариант? Разве в классе все члены класса и типы не видят друг друга, в какой бы они последовательности не были написаны?

Comment: так же, как мы не видим  каким будет следующий вопрос или ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С++ обычно требуется объявлять сущности *перед* их использованием, т.е. объявление сущности должно располагаться *над* ее использованием.

Возможность "заглядывать вперед", т.е. видеть все определение класса целиком, имеют

1. Определения *тел* методов (именно код между `{` и `}`)
2. Аргументы по умолчанию
3. BoE-инициализаторы для нестатических членов
4. Спецификатор `noexcept`

То есть вот такие "заглядывания вперед" являются допустимыми

```
class Monster
{
public:
  int i = TROLL;                // 3

  Monster(int a = VAMPIRE)      // 2
  {
    MonsterTypes t = OGRE;      // 1
  }

  void foo() noexcept(GOBLIN);  // 4

  enum MonsterTypes
  {
    DRAGON,
    GOBLIN,
    OGRE,
    ORC,
    SKELETON,
    TROLL,
    VAMPIRE,
    ZOMBIE,
    MAX_MONSTER_TYPES
  };
};
```

У объявлений параметров в списке параметров метода такой возможности нет (кроме части, ответственной за аргументы по умолчанию). Поэтому он не видит вашего `MonsterTypes`.

Comment: Верно ли то, что 2-е выполняется только тогда, когда default значение - константа времени компиляции?

Comment: @0Brains: Нет, я не вижу никакой связи с константами времени компиляции.